# What is the LibGit2Sharp equivalent of 'git checkout --ours'?

Tags: libgit2sharp

When having content conflict when merging two branches, the solution we'd like to adopt is to take our files or their files instead of using any merge tool.

In Git command, I can use --ours and theirs
git checkout --ours -- 
git checkout --theirs --

Does anyone know what is LibGit2Sharp equivalent of it?

Answer (score 0):

> When having content conflict when merging two branches, the solution we'd like to adopt is to take our files or their files instead of using any merge tool.
>   Does anyone know what is LibGit2Sharp equivalent of it?

The `Merge()` method accepts a `MergeOptions` parameter which exposes a `FileConflictStrategy` get/setter.

See this **[test](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/7a317883c304b12e4d1a742e8a61ddb751985f8d/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/MergeFixture.cs#L601-L650)** which shows how to leverage it.

> In Git command, I can use --ours and theirs git checkout --ours -- git checkout --theirs --

Surprisingly, although this option is already available for `CherryPick`, `Merge` and `Revert`, this is not available yet in LibGit2Sharp for `Checkout()` method.

To this purpose up-for-grabs feature request **[#868](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/868)** has been created.